# Get specific data from vuex store while using a route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

So I'm new to Vue and have been learning for about the past week or two. I can't seem to figure out how to get the specific physician data on the `PhysicianProfile.vue` component. I have my mock data in the store and I'm passing that information to `PhysicianListing.vue`, which is my main page to see the listing (loops through the data).

In `PhysicianFullListing.vue` I'm passing a physician prop that is expecting an Object and is building out the listing cards on `PhysicianListing.vue`. I have routes setup to build our SEO Friendly URLs (`/physician/profile/firstName-lastName-designation`).

My question is how do only get the data back for the physician that I'm currently viewing on the profile page? It seems so simple but I'm completely missing what I need to do. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

**store/store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        physicians: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Emily Been, MD',
                firstName: 'Emily',
                lastName: 'Been',
                designation: 'MD',
                specialty: 'Internal Medicine',
                locationDistance: 14,
                photo: 'https://placehold.it/75x75',
                location: {
                    title: 'TriStar Centennial',
                    address: '2300 Patterson St',
                    city: 'Nashville',
                    state: 'TN',
                    zipCode: 37203
                }
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Lisa Gomez, MD',
                firstName: 'Lisa',
                lastName: 'Gomez',
                designation: 'MD',
                specialty: 'Internal Medicine',
                locationDistance: 14,
                photo: 'https://placehold.it/75x75',
                location: {
                    title: 'TriStar Centennial',
                    address: '2300 Patterson St',
                    city: 'Nashville',
                    state: 'TN',
                    zipCode: 37203
                }
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Raymond Acevedo, MD',
                firstName: 'Raymond',
                lastName: 'Acevedo',
                designation: 'MD',
                specialty: 'Internal Medicine',
                locationDistance: 14,
                photo: 'https://placehold.it/75x75',
                location: {
                    title: 'TriStar Centennial',
                    address: '2300 Patterson St',
                    city: 'Nashville',
                    state: 'TN',
                    zipCode: 37203
                }
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Christi Mancuso, MD',
                firstName: 'Christi',
                lastName: 'Mancuso',
                designation: 'MD',
                specialty: 'Internal Medicine',
                locationDistance: 14,
                photo: 'https://placehold.it/75x75',
                location: {
                    title: 'TriStar Centennial',
                    address: '2300 Patterson St',
                    city: 'Nashville',
                    state: 'TN',
                    zipCode: 37203
                }
            }, {
                id: 5,
                name: 'Martin Mannings, MD',
                firstName: 'Martin',
                lastName: 'Mannings',
                designation: 'MD',
                specialty: 'Internal Medicine',
                locationDistance: 14,
                photo: 'https://placehold.it/75x75',
                location: {
                    title: 'TriStar Centennial',
                    address: '2300 Patterson St',
                    city: 'Nashville',
                    state: 'TN',
                    zipCode: 37203
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Axios from '@/components/Axios'
import VueResource from '@/components/VueResource'
import PhysicianListing from '@/components/PhysicianListing'
import ProgressSteps from '@/components/ProgressSteps'
import PhysicianProfile from '@/components/PhysicianProfile'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Axios',
            component: Axios
        },
        {
            path: '/resource',
            name: 'VueResource',
            component: VueResource
        },
        {
            path: '/physicians',
            name: 'physician-listing',
            component: PhysicianListing
        },
        {
            path: '/physicians/profile/:firstName-:lastName-:designation',
            name: 'pd-profile',
            component: PhysicianProfile
        },
        {
            path: '/progress',
            name: 'progress-steps',
            component: ProgressSteps
        }
    ]
})
```

**PhysicianFullListing.vue** Reusable Component

```
<template>
    <li class="pd-item">
        <div class="pd-header d-flex align-items-start">
            <div class="pd-number">{{physician.id}}</div>
            <img :src="physician.photo" alt="" class="pd-photo rounded-circle mr-4">
            <div class="pd-info">
                <h2 class="pd-title">{{physician.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{physician.specialty}}</p>
                <p class="pd-location">
                    <span class="pd-miles">
                        <i class="material-icons">place</i> {{physician.locationDistance}} miles away
                    </span><br>
                    {{physician.location.title}}<br>
                    {{physician.location.address}},<br>
                    {{physician.location.city}}, {{physician.location.state}} {{physician.location.zipCode}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pd-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="pd-rating">
                <span class="material-icons star-rating">star</span>
                <span class="material-icons star-rating">star</span>
                <span class="material-icons star-rating">star</span>
                <span class="material-icons star-rating">star</span>
                <span class="material-icons star-rating">star</span>
            </div>
            <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'pd-profile', params: {firstName: physician.firstName, lastName: physician.lastName, designation: physician.designation}}">
                View Profile
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'physician-full-listing',
    props: {
        physician: Object
    },
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'Physicians Full Listing'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**PhysicianListing.vue** Reusing Components

```
<template>
    <div class="physician-listing">
        <h1 class="mt-3 mb-3 text-center">{{msg}}</h1>
        <physician-filters></physician-filters>
        <physician-search></physician-search>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pd-list-column col-4">
                <p class="results-txt">Showing 1-5 of {{physicians.length}} results</p>
                <ul class="pd-listing list-unstyled">
                    <physician-full-listing v-for="physician in physicians" :key="physician.id" :physician="physician"></physician-full-listing>
                </ul>
                <div class="fixed-action-btn">
                    <router-link to="/progress" class="btn-floating blue">
                        <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <google-map name="example"></google-map>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import GoogleMap from '@/components/GoogleMap'
import PhysicianFilters from '@/components/physicians/PhysicianFilters'
import PhysicianSearch from '@/components/physicians/PhysicianSearch'
import PhysicianFullListing from '@/components/physicians/PhysicianFullListing'

export default {
    name: 'physician-listing',
    components: {
        PhysicianFullListing,
        GoogleMap,
        PhysicianFilters,
        PhysicianSearch
    },
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'Make an Appointment',
        }
    },
    computed: {
        physicians() {
            return this.$store.state.physicians
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**PhysicianProfile.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="physician-profile">
        <h1 class="mb-5">{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'pd-profile',
        data () {
            return {
                msg: 'Physician Profile'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, by adding `props: true` to your route object, you can pass in the route parameters as props to your PhysicianProfile component

```
    {
        path: '/physicians/profile/:firstName-:lastName-:designation',
        name: 'pd-profile',
        component: PhysicianProfile,
        props: true
    },
```

Then you can add those three props to your PhysicianProfile component, and set up a Vuex getter to fetch the physician:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getPhysicianByDetails: (state) => (firstName, lastName, designation) => {
    return state.physicians.find(phys => phys.firstName === firstName && phys.lastName === lastName && phys.designation === designation)
  }
}
```

Check these out for further reading

https://medium.com/vue-by-example/learn-quickly-passing-params-as-props-with-vue-router-f4905735b747

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass props through the URL, in this case, the Physician ID. Then you can fetch the physician in the created lifecycle hook :)

To make the explanation a bit easier I'll add an id to your path (/physician/profile/**id**/firstName-lastName-designation). You can change the find method in the created hook to suite your needs :)

```
// Router
  {
     path: '/physicians/profile/:id/:firstName-:lastName-:designation',
     name: 'pd-profile',
     component: PhysicianProfile,
     props: true
  },
```

You then need to set the props and fetch the physician in **PhisicianProfile.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="physician-profile">
        <h1 class="mb-5">{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'pd-profile',
        props: {
            id: {
                required: true
            },
            // rest of the props if needed
        },
        data () {
            return {
                msg: 'Physician Profile',
            }
        },

        created () {
            // Fetch the physician with based on this.id
            const physician = this.$store.state.physicians.find((physician) => { return physician.id == this.id })
            // Do something with physician (set to data and use in template)
        }
    }
</script>
```

For more information about passing props, check out the [vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) :)

Comment: when you say set to data what do you mean? When I console physician out I see the object so I'm guessing you mean add a new item under data (maybe an empty array) and set physician equal to it.

Comment: you should use a Vuex getter, not just pull the physician out, to make sure its reactive to changes in Vuex.

Comment: mcallaro, you understood me right, set an empty object/array in the data that will hold what you fetch. Jeff is also right, you should use a getter to fetch the data from Vuex. I interpreted your question mostly as a vue router question, how to pass a param. If you want to learn Vuex, check out our course: [Vuex for Everyone](https://vueschool.io/courses/vuex-for-everyone)

Comment: Thank you both for you're answers. I was able to get it working with the getters the first time around just wanted to see if there were other options. Thanks again.